# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getToken on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play

On my release version of my flutter android app I am getting this error.

I have tried:

Updating the SHA-1 Key from Google Play Console in Firebase
Updating google-services.json
Rebuilding and rolling out.

I still get this error.
I have INTERNET_PERMISSIONS enabled and cleartext=true as well.

App works fine in iOS and android debug mode as well.

2021-02-15 00:47:37.450 2888-2932/? E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method configure on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157)

2021-02-15 00:47:37.450 2888-2932/? E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getToken on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157)

#1      FirebaseMessaging.getToken (package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart:146)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make sure you have implemented following steps:

1:  Add dep in pubspecs.yaml

```
firebase_core: // latest version
firebase_messaging: // latest version
```

2: Add dependency & service in the app `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {

 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')
 
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
 
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

3: proper **google-service.json** under `app` directory only

4: Initialization in `main.dart`

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

5: Add this code in your main class or 1st executing class

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((token){
  print("token $token");
});
```

Comment: can you add logs from installing app to the error you are receiving? So i can understand exact issue

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention this. Did you initialize firebase app like this ? Firebase.initializeApp()

Comment: No, where would I initialize it?

Comment: @TamimChowdhury ive updated my answer with step 4 : Initialization, Please check it

Comment: In the version of firebase you are mentioning, the FirebaseMessaging() is deprecated in favor of FirebaseMessaging.instance or FirebaseMessaging.instanceFor() instead.

Comment: thanks @Akah I will correct it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following in your pubspec.yaml (and run an implicit flutter pub get):

```
dependencies:
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.9
```

Imported,
Now in your Dart code, you can use:

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
```

Then in your class here's a method you might want to use, maybe for subscribing to  topic:

```
Future<void> subscribeToChallenge(String topic) async {
    // subscribe to topic on when user clicks join
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(topic);

  }
```

notice the initializeApp() call again even when you already have such in the main file? Yeah, somehow that's how i got it to work by intuition.

Answer (score -1):

Add this dependency in the app `build.gradle` file.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
```

Comment: I already have     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'