# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_firestore/document/

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting this error:

```dart
I/flutter (20730): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_firestore/document/bd4e8cf9-3f97-4dc6-998c-0c53c3666889)
I/flutter (20730): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:165)
I/flutter (20730): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (20730): #1      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:506)
I/flutter (20730): <asynchronous suspension>
```

This is only happening on the live android app (the app downloaded from the play store), the debug apps are working fine, and also this issue is not happening on `All` production apps

I tried downgrading `cloud_firestore:` from `3.2.0` to `2.0.0` and still got the same error

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66202987/missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-gettoken-on-channel-pl

Comment: @flexagoon the post u shared is regarding firebase messaging, my issue is with cloud_firestore, i checked the content of the post u shared and its invalid to my case